# How do I read a csv File with pandas that has multiple values in one column?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, read.csv

I have a csv file that looks like this:

```
timestamp (int), array(value1,value2,...), identifier (string)
```

The arrays with the values inside are exactly written like this:

```
List(value1, value2, value3)
```

where the values can be written in the formats

```
1.23E4, -123456.78910
```

So what I want to have eventually is a dataframe with a timestamp and an identifier, but multiple values at each point.

I have no idea how to read this csv file with pandas in python. If I just try

```
pd.read_csv("myFilePath")
```

it gives me

```
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 7 fields in line 3, saw 76
```

Obviously I didnt tell pandas how to read that file properly and honestly I dont quite know hot to. Can somebody help me?
Thanks a lot

Comment: How do you want the list values represented?  A real list in a single column?

Answer (score 0):

You could just read in all the data where each row was represented in a single column then extract what you need from there.

**I think your data may look like this**

```
sim_csv = io.StringIO(
'''2022-07-20,List(1.23E4, -123456.78910),ID001
2022-07-21,List(2.23E4, -223456.78910),ID002
2022-07-22,List(3.23E4, -323456.78910),ID003
2022-07-23,List(4.23E4, -423456.78910, 55),ID004''')
```

**Read it all in - single column**

```
df = pd.read_fwf(sim_csv, widths=[999999], header=None)
print(df)

                                                  0
0      2022-07-20,List(1.23E4, -123456.78910),ID001
1      2022-07-21,List(2.23E4, -223456.78910),ID002
2      2022-07-22,List(3.23E4, -323456.78910),ID003
3  2022-07-23,List(4.23E4, -423456.78910, 55),ID004
```

**Extract what you need**

```
dfs = df[0].str.extract(r'(?P<timestamp>.+),.*List\((?P<raw_values>.+)\),(?P<id>.+)')
print(dfs)

    timestamp                 raw_values     id
0  2022-07-20      1.23E4, -123456.78910  ID001
1  2022-07-21      2.23E4, -223456.78910  ID002
2  2022-07-22      3.23E4, -323456.78910  ID003
3  2022-07-23  4.23E4, -423456.78910, 55  ID004
```

That leave your in a list that is really still a string and not a Python list object.  Not sure what you want to do with the values from there.  Maybe make them into a real list.

**Values to a real list**

```
dfs['list_values'] = dfs['raw_values'].str.split(',')
print(dfs)

    timestamp                 raw_values     id                    list_values
0  2022-07-20      1.23E4, -123456.78910  ID001       [1.23E4,  -123456.78910]
1  2022-07-21      2.23E4, -223456.78910  ID002       [2.23E4,  -223456.78910]
2  2022-07-22      3.23E4, -323456.78910  ID003       [3.23E4,  -323456.78910]
3  2022-07-23  4.23E4, -423456.78910, 55  ID004  [4.23E4,  -423456.78910,  55]
```

At this point the values in the list are actually still strings.  There are a lot of things you could do from here depending on what you are trying to accomplish.